# Vertical Federated Learning

Tags: machine-learning, validation, tensorflow

Lately I have been working (mostly reading) on Federated Learning and the one type of federation that looks suitable for my case is the *Vertical Federated Learning*. You can read about it [here](https://blog.openmined.org/federated-learning-types/). Briefly, lets say a Bank and an online Retailer collaboratively wants to develop a machine learning model without sharing actual personal data, to help prevent fraud. Bank knows about the persons credit details and the retailer knows about purchase history.

While I understand how the training is made possible using clients having different schema collaborating to develop a common model, the problem I face understanding is how the testing would take place.

*e.g.,* lets say two clients C1 and C2 have commonly developed a model M. After training and collaborative testing, C1 wants to deploy that model in production. Now in order C1 to have live data predictions, will C1 need data points from C2 too, since both have contributed in the training equally?